# MVC Decimal Separator with multiple culture

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I'm working with an application with multiple culture, and when i change culture 'pt' to 'en' the decimal separator change to. Have some way to fixing the decimal separator?

thanks.

Comment: I suggest you re-tag this for `.net` and `globalization` : it's not MVC related.

Comment: Question: Why are you changing the culture to `en` if you don't like the standard `en` settings, as they are appropriate for an `en` culture user? Perhaps your question really is `how to fix the culture`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056658/why-is-thread-currentthread-currentculture-name-showing-en-us-when-my-servers/6056725#6056725

Answer (score 5):

Roll your own `CultureInfo` by modifying the standard one:

```
var cInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us");

cInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
cInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
cInfo.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ",";

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInfo;
```

Comment: thanks, good solution, but any idea to run through the application?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: So, I'm working in an application MVC, this application support mutiple culture. Your 'CultureInfo' exemple, working very good. But I have to get one solution to affect all the application. like a base class. thank u Zruty.

Comment: In my application, all my controllers inherit from my superclass called `UIController`, which determines the client's language in its `Initialize` method. You can also implement this via custom filters.